# Is it possible to create template variable for p-dropdown for template-driven form validation?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have p-dropdown element in template

```
  <p-dropdown id="output-method" [options]="outputMethods" [(ngModel)]="transformer!.outputMethod"
              pTooltip="Output Method" tooltipPosition="bottom"
              [showDelay]="350" [hideDelay]="350" #outputMethod="ngModel"
              [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid ng-dirty': !transformer?.outputMethod}"></p-dropdown>
```

here I'm trying to use it for validation using value

```
<div [hidden]="outputMethod?.value?.valid || outputMethod?.value?.untouched" class="alert alert-danger">
      Outpup Method is required!
    </div>
```

but its not working. How I should check that this field was touched? which property instead of value should be used?
Can this first element impact in enum?

```
    export enum OutputMethod {
      '' = '\xa0', //still not fixed https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/3964
//other elements
    }
```

Comment: The name of the variable is `outputMethod`, not `outputMethodVar`. So you're supposed to access `outputMethod.value`, `outputMethod.value.valid`, and such.

Comment: thanks, but original code contains correct value "outputMethod", edited

Comment: @ovod you need to remove the intermediate `value` property from your checks. `[hidden]="outputMethod?.valid || outputMethod?.untouched"`

Comment: valid and untouched are colored in red after that(Unresolved variable valid ) - it seems that its not valid, I tried to do that firstly

Comment: I don't know if its possible with p-dropdown element - it works perfect with input/select html elements

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking into **ControlValueAccessor**.

Can you check [angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)

And look into this stackblitz example

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-control-value-accessor-simple-example-tsmean-dmmoaa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)